# HTML - What is the correct tags i should use?

Tags: html, tags, html-lists

I'm creating a simple notes SPA for my portfolio and i'm wondering what would be the correct HTML tags to use while creating the sidebar. I was using lists like everybody else but after i read an article about how listless navbars are better to SR (screen reader) users, i'm thinking about said technique, so instead of this:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Help</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

We have this:

```
<div>
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>About</a>
  <a>Help</a>
  <a>Contact</a>
</div>
```

But then again, the navbar i'm creating does not technically includes links, but more like actions, like this:

```
/* Clicking shows saved notes */

<div class="nav-item">
  <div class="nav-item__inner-ctr">
   <i class="note-icon"></i>
   <span>Notes</span>
  </div>
</div>

/* Queries through saved notes */

<div class="nav-item">
  <div class="nav-item__inner-ctr">
   <i class="search-icon"></i>  
   <span>Search</span>
  <div>     
</div>
```

You get the point. So what should i use to group these elements? Thanks for your help in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: "I was using lists like everybody else but after i read an article about how listless navbars are better to SR (screen reader) users" — Now look at it in a text browser and see if you can tell where one link ends and the next begins (you have to infer it from what words look stand-along and which look like they are multiple words making up one thing): https://imgur.com/a/LHDccar — **Write semantic HTML**.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a set of navigation links? Use a [`nav` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav).

Is it a list of things? Use an [unordered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) or [ordered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) list.

Is it something that the user is supposed to click on which isn't a link? Use a [button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Is it multiple of these things? Combine multiple of these things.